# IF ELSE function works in simple case, but my expanded function does not

Tags: r

I am trying to create functions that evaluates numbers and adds them to a category dependent on set criteria.

I wrote a "stupid" function with a lot of repetitions and lines, that can solve the job in a simple case:

```
# Findgroup (Everything manually typed out)
# Purpose of function:
#If 1 or 2: output A
#If 3 or 4: output B
#If 5 or 6: output random A/B (bonus if this can be balanced equally over the dataset)
# Else output "error"
findGroup <- function(x){ if (x == 1) { 
  "A"
} else if (x == 2) {
  "A"
} else if  (x == 3) {
  "B"
} else if  (x == 4) {
  "B"
}else if  (x == 5) {
  sample(c("sA","sB"),1)
}else if  (x == 6) {
  sample(c("sA","sB"),1)
} else {
  "Error"
}}

# Brief test: All matches expectations
findGroup(1) # Returns A
findGroup(3) # Returns B
findGroup(5) # Samples
findGroup(7) # Returns Error
```

This is okay, if I had to evaluate a few numbers. But what should I do if the list of numbers is much more elaborate? I tried to write a function that solves this in fewer lines, but the result does not work:

```
# Findgroup new
# Purpose of function:
#If 2:8: output A
#If 10:16: output B
#If 1,9: output random A/B (bonus if this can be balanced equally)
findGroupNew <- function(x){ if (x == 2|3|4|5|6|7|8) { 
  "A"
} else if (x == 10|11|12|13|14|15|16) {
  "B"
} else if (x == 1||9) {
  sample(c("sA","sB"),1)
} else {
  "Error"
}}

# Brief test: All return A!!!
findGroupNew(1) # Should sample
findGroupNew(3) # Should Return A
findGroupNew(11) # Should Return B
findGroupNew(17) # Should Return Error
```

It may be a stupid mistake such as not having used the right sign for OR, but having tried solutions such as using || and & has not been successful.

I hope there is a quick fix to this issue and will appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%in%` to check for multiple values.

```
findGroupNew <- function(x) { 
   if (x %in% 2:6) { 
    return("A")
  } else if (x %in% 10:16) {
    return("B")
  } else if (x %in% c(1, 9)) {
    return(sample(c("sA","sB"),1))
  } else {
    return("Error")
  }
}

findGroupNew(1)
#[1] "sB"
findGroupNew(3)
#[1] "A"
findGroupNew(11)
#[1] "B"
findGroupNew(7)
#[1] "Error"
```